# Simple dumb image viewer, with CLI access

Tags: command-line, image-viewers

I am looking for a simple, dumb image viewing program, something that I can fire up from the command line.  *Ideally* this would be `xv` (is this available for Ubuntu 14.04?).  I just need something that lets me look at files in `/usr/share/icons/` etc.  An important (necessary!) feature: it needs to work from the command line.  I am sshing into the Ubuntu machine (from a CentOS machine, but that is neither here nor there) -- I am NOT on the Ubuntu machine's console.

Comment: Why can't you use X Forwarding and the default image viewer (`eog`)?

Comment: Mostly because I did not know about eog.  I am not vastly familar with Ubuntu or what packages are installed by default. Doing an 'apropos image' did not turn up anything useful -- I'm guessing that eog probably does not have a useful man page -- man pages are pretty much going out of style, so tools like apropos at the command line are no longer as useful as they once were.  (Remember I am not doing this at the Ubuntu machine's console, so I don't have access to the GUI search thingy.

Comment: Bad luck, I suppose. I tried `apropos viewer`, and `eog` was the second term for me. (`image` would be just too broad, I think).

Answer (score 3):

Feh is a fast, lightweight image viewer. You can install *feh* from the default Ubuntu repositories.

It is commandline-driven and supports multiple images through slideshows, thumbnail browsing or multiple windows, and montages or index prints (using TrueType fonts to display file info). Advanced features include fast dynamic zooming, progressive  loading, loading via HTTP (with reload support for watching webcams), recursive file opening (slideshow of a directory hierarchy), and mouse wheel/keyboard control.

Answer (score 0):

A very lightweight image viewer comes with the [xloadimage [image: Install xloadimage]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xloadimage) package to display an image in a window, provided an X-Server is running.

There are many options we can control from the command line (e. -zoom, -fit, -fullscreen etc.). Supported image formats for viewing are niff, sunraster, gif, jpeg, tiff, png, fbm, cmuraster, bpm, faces, rle, xwd, vff, mcidas, vicar, ocx, gem, macpaint, xpm, and xbm.

To view an image:

```
xview path/to/image
```

There are no further mouse controls other than closing with a right click.